# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. build.gradle' line: 24 Flutter

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

run project...

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

-> Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file com/android/build/api/artifact/impl/StorageProviderImpl

Answer (score 0):

edit gradle-wrapper.properties file in [yourProject]/android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties

replace: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

to: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

change distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties
to

> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

hope it helps.